# Why is 'M' matching when I asked for 'A' to match in this regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this string:

```
    A /Modules/framework/odd-core/tags
```

(it does start with spaces). I am trying to match it using

```
\s+A\s+\/Modules\/\w\/\w\/branches|trunk|tags$
```

That works fine, but it is also matching:

```
    M /Modules/framework/buildtools/trunk/modules-parent/pom.xml
```

I have specifically asked for it to match the character 'A', but it's also picking up the character 'M'

Comment: `\s+A\s+\/Modules\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/(?:branches|trunk|tags)$` works thank you @ctwheels

Comment: The `\s+` at the beginning requires at least one space at the beginning of the target string. It cannot match the "_string_" you show, which starts with `A` and not space. Is that "_string_" in fact text in a larger string?  You got a complete answer but I suggest that you edit the question and clarify this point with a small comment.

Comment: FYI, instead of trying to parse `svn` output, you might just want to use [SVN::Client from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm).

Comment: The markup requires 4 spaces before the string to mark it up so i don't know how to indicate that there should be additional spaces

Comment: @eeijlar: Uh, five spaces? Had you noticed that indentation works just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex isn't matching `M`: it's matching `trunk`. Your regex pattern currently says:

- Match any of the following patterns

  - `\s+A\s+\/Modules\/\w\/\w\/branches`
  - `trunk`
  - `tags$`

To fix this you need to group the options together such that the alternates `|` are separate from the rest of the pattern. Using a "non-capturing group" `(?: ... )` works fine.

Another issue you're facing is with the `\w` character class. It matches a *single character* in the set `A-Za-z0-9_`. It looks like you need to match `odd-core` which will fail because of the hyphen `-` and because it is more than one character. You need to add to the character class and use `[\w-]+` which will match the whole substring.

You *could* use `[^/]+` (change the delimiters of the regex to avoid escaping slashes) but that will match *any character at all* except for a slash.

As mentioned in comments below the OP's question as well as my answer, we aren't sure what the `\s+` in your pattern is used for as there are no whitespaces characters at the start of your string. You may be able to remove the `\s+` altogether or change the quantifier to `*` instead (any number of whitespace characters rather than one or more whitespace characters) if your strings don't actually contain leading whitespace.

#### Code

Either of the following methods works.

[See the first regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ezC8c8/2)

[See the second regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ezC8c8/1)

```
\s+A\s+\/Modules(?:\/[^\/]+){2}\/(?:branches|trunk|tags)$
\s+A\s+\/Modules\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/(?:branches|trunk|tags)$
```

Comment: Apologies, there are actually spaces before the 'A' character.

Comment: @eeijlar I edited your question to add spaces.  In the future perhaps write a note?

Comment: @zdim no worries, thanks for the edit and cleaning up your comments, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- I assume you have code something like this

  ```
  my $str = 'A /Modules/framework/odd-core/tags';

  if ( $str =~ /\s+A\s+\/Modules\/\w\/\w\/branches|trunk|tags$/ ) { ... }
  ```
- First of all, if you're writing a pattern that matches slashes `/` then it's much simpler to change to a different delimiter. We can do that with any non-space character like `!` as long as there's an `m` in front

  ```
  if ( $str =~ m!\s+A\s+/Modules/\w/\w/branches|trunk|tags$! ) { ... }
  ```
- Now there are no spaces before the `A` in your string, so the initial `\s+` won't match. Let's remove it

  ```
  if ( $str =~ m!A\s+/Modules/\w/\w/branches|trunk|tags$! ) { ... }
  ```
- Now you're trying to match `framework` and `odd-core` with just `\w`, which matches only a *single* alphanumeric character or an underscore. Let's add a hyphen `-` to make a new character class `[\w-]` and append a `+` to match "one or more"

  ```
  if ( $str =~ m!A\s+/Modules/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/branches|trunk|tags$! ) { ... }
  ```
- Now you're matching `A\s+/Modules/framework/odd-core` ***or*** `trunk` ***or*** `tags$`. Let's put in non-capturing parentheses to make it say what I think you mean

  ```
  if ( $str =~ m!A\s+/Modules/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/(?:branches|trunk|tags)$! ) { ... }
  ```

  That should work!

#### Update

Since your question has been updated to show that there really are spaces before the `A` you may add back the initial `\s+`, but I think the pattern is likely to be fine without it

Comment: They explained that spaces are indeed there and commented that they didn't know how to enter them.  So I edited the question and did that ... I hope that you don't mind, as it changes things. Perhaps add a note about the change?  Or, of course, by all means please roll back my change in the question if that's better.

Comment: @zdim: Far from it; I'm grateful for your support.